# Attempt to delete row 2 from section 1 which only contains 2 rows before the update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to delete a row in a UITableView using a swipe action but keep receiving the following error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 2 from section 1 which only contains 2 rows before the update'

The tableview has multiple sections.

Code below:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return favouriteSubjectTitlesArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    
   return favouriteCaseIDsBySubjectArray[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
 if orientation == .left {
    //Unfavourite the case
    let unfavouriteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Unfavourite") { action, indexPath in

    self.favouriteCaseIDsBySubjectArray[self.selectedSubjectID].remove(at: indexPath.row)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
      }
    }
return [unfavouriteAction]
  }
return nil
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: There is an inconsistency: In `numberOfSections` there is `favouriteSubjectTitlesArray` and in `numberOfRowsInSection` there is `favouriteCaseIDsBySubjectArray` representing the sections. The datasource doesn't like inconsistencies. And you should delete from `indexPath.section`

Comment: Ok, will try and streamline that. What do you mean by delete from `indexPath.section`?

Comment: You should use `self.favouriteCaseIDsBySubjectArray[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)` to ensure you are deleting from the correct array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the solution: after updating the datasource with a struct, I found that you need to add `action.fulfill(with: .delete)` for `SwipeCellKit`.

Working code is therefore:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
 if orientation == .left {
    //Unfavourite the case
    let unfavouriteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Unfavourite") { action, indexPath in

        self.favouriteCases.remove(at: indexPath)

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
        action.fulfill(with: .delete)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

   return [unfavouriteAction]
  }
return nil
}
```